# Apply function on list in pyspark column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

```
>> df = hc.createDataFrame([('a', [1.0, 1.0]), ('a',[1.0, 0.2,0.3,0.7]), ('b', [1.0]),('c' ,[1.0, 0.5]), ('d', [0.55, 1.0,1.4]),('e', [1.05, 1.0])])


>> df.show()
+---+--------------------+
| _1|                  _2|
+---+--------------------+
|  a|          [1.0, 1.0]|
|  a|[1.0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7]|
|  b|               [1.0]|
|  c|          [1.0, 0.5]|
|  d|    [0.55, 1.0, 1.4]|
|  e|         [1.05, 1.0]|
+---+--------------------+
```

Now, I want to apply a function like a sum or mean on the column, "_2" to create a column, "_3"
For example, I created a column using the sum function
The result should look like below

```
+---+--------------------+----+
| _1|                  _2|  _3|
+---+--------------------+----+
|  a|          [1.0, 1.0]| 2.0|
|  a|[1.0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7]| 2.2|
|  b|               [1.0]| 1.0|
|  c|          [1.0, 0.5]| 1.5|
|  d|    [0.55, 1.0, 1.4]|2.95|
|  e|         [1.05, 1.0]|2.05|
+---+--------------------+----+
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** Unless you use [proprietary extensions](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/higher-order-functions-lambda-functions.html) you have to define an `UserDefinedFunction` for each operation:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import numpy as np

@udf("double")
def array_sum(xs):
    return np.sum(xs).tolist() if xs is not None else None

@udf("double")
def array_mean(xs):
    return np.mean(xs).tolist() if xs is not None else None

(df
    .withColumn("mean", array_mean("_2"))
    .withColumn("sum", array_sum("_2")))
```

In some cases you might prefer to `explode` and aggregate, but it has limited applications and is typically much more expensive, unless data is already partitioned by unique identifier.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id, first, mean, sum, explode

(df
    .withColumn("_id", monotonically_increasing_id()).withColumn("x", explode("_2"))
    .groupBy("_id")
    .agg(first("_1"), first("_2"), mean("x"), sum("x")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: But rather than using a decorator function, I tried to register the function udf and perform the same operation. I received below error
    TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
I couldn't get the magic done by decorator here - can you please explain ??